Using the JSR223 ScriptEngine in Kotlin, how to insert a typed object into the bindings?
Let's say I get the script bindings like this and then insert a map:
val sbi = scriptContext.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE)
val mymap = mutableMapOf<String, SomeObject>(...)
sbi["_map"] = mymap

Now within a script I try to use this object:
_map["foo"].somefield

This results in: Exception: ERROR Unresolved reference: somefield
The problem is that the binding does not know about the type of the object.
There's a workaround that proves this theory.  I can do this in the script:
val map: MutableMap<String, SomeObject> get() = (bindings["_map"] as MutableMap<String, SomeObject>)

Now using "map" works fine.  This feels ugly; it leaves an "unusable" object (_map) in the namespace and it feels inefficient.  I was wondering if anyone knows how to initially set up the binding with types so this workaround is unnecessary.
